# Bootstrap 4 navbar collapsable for mobile devices

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to put together a Bootstrap navbar which will collapse when displayed on a mobile devices.

I have been following a tutorial but for some reason when I reduce the window size the navbar disappears not collapsing. Can anyone see where I have gone wrong.

I am using the following in this order in the header:
bootstrap.css Bootstrap v4.0.0
jquery-3.2.1.min.js
bootstrap.min Bootstrap v4.0.0

My code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-top"> 
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu1">
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#facilities">Facilities</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link"  data-target="#benefits">Benefits</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link"  data-target="#spinaltherapy">Equine Spinal Therapy</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link"  data-target="#contact">Contact and location</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#gallery">Gallery</a> 
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> 
        <a class="nav-link"  data-target="#workwith">Who we work with</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the toggler styles which make it visible, do not get applied unless it is within `.navbar-light` or `.navbar-dark`
i.e.:

```
  .navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
    background-image: escape-svg($navbar-light-toggler-icon-bg);
  }
```

So just add `.navbar-light` and you will be able to see the button and icon. Also consider using `.bg-light` or use `.navbar-dark.bg-dark` for a dark navbar.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu1">
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#facilities">Facilities</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#benefits">Benefits</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#spinaltherapy">Equine Spinal Therapy</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#contact">Contact and location</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#gallery">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-target="#workwith">Who we work with</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your time and a solution. working now.